# Problem with Textmaker 4.5 + bibtex + Windows 10 + MiKTeX 2.9 "print References"?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing

Running the minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

simple example \cite{Rn123}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

where `References.bib` is

```
@article{Rn123,
   author = {Rosenthal, Arnie},
   title = {Computing the reliability of complex networks},
   journal = {SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics},
   volume = {32},
   number = {2},
   pages = {384-393},
   ISSN = {0036-1399},
   year = {1977},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

I do not get any result and do not print the bibliography as in the picture
[image]

When I run the Bibtex show these errors[image]

Note I'm using Textmaker 4.5  with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10 ,
  I saw a lot of lessons on Youtube and did not work with me ways to solve the problem and I saw a lot of questions here and did not find a solution.

Please help me with many thanks

this pictures of example  and textmaker option[image]
 [image]

When I use  [TeXmaker answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/35864) get [image]

Comment: With your document set-up you will need to run Biber and not BibTeX. See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) on hints to run Biber instead of BibTeX.

Comment: BTW: Use `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` or `\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]` instead of `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}`.

Comment: @moewe Can you explain the way to me as steps ... I'm starting at Latex

Comment: Just have a look at the [TeXmaker answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788/35864) of the question I linked to and follow the steps. Essentially you will have to change the settings for 'Bib(la)tex'. Where you now have `bibtex %` you need to have `biber %`.

Comment: @moewe The method did not work the same as the error

Comment: Mhhh, that can't be. If the entry in 'Bib(la)tex' really reads `biber %` now you can't get 'This is BibTeX'. Please share a screenshot of your new configuration. Can you get the command line to run? What happens if you type `biber --version`?

Comment: @moewe see new update

Comment: Now this is an entirely different error. And the error message is quite clear. Your versions of `biblatex` and Biber don't match. Biber 2.5 is too old for your `biblatex` 3.7, you want Biber 2.7. Make an update of all packages involved. See [How should one maintain and update a MiKTeX installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864) for help on updating MikTeX properly.

Comment: @moewe I do not understand how to update Biber

Comment: You need to update MikTeX. Run 'MikTeX Update' and 'MikTeX Update (Admin)' two times each. Please have a look at the answer I linked to in my last comment, https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex and https://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/updating.html

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much ... The problem has been solved